# Getting rid of the commas from a CSV file?

Tags: java, csv, arraylist

I have the following code where I take values from a csv file and put them into an ArrayList so that I can use them to plug into a math equation.

```
    public class Example1
{
public static void main(String[] args) throws InvalidFormatException, IOException{
    ArrayList arr=new ArrayList();
File f=new File("C:\\java\\marchcalllast.csv");
Scanner in=new Scanner(f);
while(in.hasNext())
{    
arr.add(in.next());
}
System.out.println("Data From ArrayList");
int size = arr.size();
System.out.println(arr);
System.out.println(size);

for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++){
  String item = (String) arr.get(i);
System.out.println("Item " + i + " : " + item);
}
```

The output gives me

```
Item 0 : 15.9,

Item 1 : 13.7,

Item 2 : 12.35,

Item 3 : 10,

Item 4 : 8.45,

Item 5 : 7.15,

Item 6 : 6,

Item 7 : 5.1,

Item 8 : 4.3,

Item 9 : 3.55,
```

I want to get rid of the comma after these values to use them to insert into a mathematical equation. Is there any way to do that? Also since those values are strings, can I use them for math equations?

Comment: If you're doing this "for real", use a library. CSV is quite a multi-headed monster.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a delimiter to split by `,`. It will also ignore the comma after splitting the String.

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(input).useDelimiter(",");
```

Or you try to use this to remove the commas

```
item.replace(",","");
```

Comment: Great duplicate answer - like, 6 mins after me :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [String.split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) to split a line of text into an array of Strings.  For example:

**Part 1: Getting String values between the commas**

`String line = "13.7, 12.35, 10, 8.45";
String[] elements = line.split(",");
// elements = "13.7", " 12.35", " 10", " 8.45"`

To make sure you're just getting the number (and not any spaces), you can tweak the regex to something like this:

`line.split("\\s*,\\s*")`

**Part 2: Converting Strings to Doubles for Mathematical Calculations**

Your numbers look like they are decimal numbers.  So you can use [Double.valueOf()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#valueOf%28java.lang.String%29) to convert them to Doubles.

`Double.valueOf("1.2")`

Comment: Thanks for the answer everyone I really appreciate it. I used "useDelimiter" and it worked! But where would I insert Double.valueOf()?

Answer (score 0):

Provider your `Scanner` with a delimiter (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#useDelimiter(java.lang.String)) so it will get rid of the commas by itself.

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(f).useDelimiter(",");
```